# Filling up a NumPy array based on the index of the element

Tags: python, numpy

Assume:
`u = 1.2`
`d = 0.8`
`n = 3`
I was wondering how I can get an array with 3 (n) elements where the value of each element is:

The solution to variables above would be:

```
[1.2^2 + 0.8^0, 1.2^1 + 0.8^1, 1.2^0 + 0.8^1]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like a line is missing from your question. And where do you use `u` and `d`?

Comment: Can you write a function of `np.arange(n)`?

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this with [Basic slicing and indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html).

```
import numpy as np

u=1.2
d=0.8
n=3

array=np.zeros(n)

for i in range(n):
    if i + 1 <= n:
        array[i:n]=u**(n-i-1)
        array[i:n] =d**(i)
```